# Unable to add window warning in android app

Tags: android, service, gps, android-context

I am trying to open a dialogue of settings from a service, but while running it, it is giving warning `WindowManagerBadTokenException- unable to add window.` Why it is giving such warning? The code is given below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class FirstService extends Service {

    Timer t;
    int time = 0;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        Log.e("time", time+++"");
        lat_long();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

    }


    public void lat_long() {
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String timerr1 = formatter.format(date);
        String timerr2 = formatter1.format(date);

        if (gps.canGetLocation) {
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            String ph = "8445590443";
            //"9639002709";

            if (latitude > 0 && longitude > 0) {
                sendSMS(ph, "LOC=" + latitude + "=" + longitude + "=" + timerr1 + "=" + timerr2);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("time", timerr1 + "and" + timerr2);

        }


    }


    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        /*
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, test.class), 0);                
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
        */

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);



        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {


            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {


                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:

                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:

                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));


        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:

                    break;
                }

            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));


        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, pi1);

    }
}
```

Another class which I am calling in my service for Turning on GPS is:

```
package test.sai;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;



    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    boolean hasLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;


    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled || !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
                showSettingsAlert();
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                Log.e("enabled", "before progress bar");


            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your trace?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong `Context`

A `BroadcastReceiver` or a `Service` cannot start a Dialog.

You should make an `Activity` with a dialog theme and launch it with `startActivity()`

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: @lon Aalber ,actually I am a novice in this and really confused,I have created one activity to launch my service and service will continue in execution but not the activity,service must check time to time whether GPS is on or not,an if it is not it will launch the dialog of settings.so how can i do this .? one more thing,when I am calling GPS class (in which dialog is defined)from any activity,it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot show Dialog from Service.

How about showing notification to user if GPS is not activated and once user click on notification you can take him to settings screen.(This is recommended approach if you want to notify use from service.)

Below tutorial will give you good understanding on how to show Notifications in android.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html